# Use Spring.NET with NHibernate 3

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, spring.net

I am trying to use the sping.net nhibernate integration with the latest nhibernate 3 release. Unfortunately spring.net references nhibernate 2.1.2.4000.

I tried to fix it with an assembly redirect to 3.0.0.1002 but this yields the error:

The method "IsInstrumented" in Type "Spring.Data.NHibernate.Bytecode.ProxyFactoryFactory" of Assembly "Spring.Data.NHibernate21, Version=1.3.0.20349, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=65e474d141e25e07" does not hava an implementation.

Any way to get NHibernate 3.0 to work with Spring.NET?

Thank you very much

Comment: [This issue](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPRNET-1181) on their JIRA tracker suggests that the problem you described has already been resolved. Are you sure you have the latest version of Spring.Net?

Comment: tried it with 1.3.0 and 1.3.0 RC1. Didn't work. In the nightly build a NHibernate3 project/dll is included - I'll go with the nightly build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest "nightly builds" of Spring.NET 1.3.0 provides support for NH 3.0.0.1002 without requiring an assembly redirect declaration.  Note that support for NH3 under Spring.NET is experimental only until NH3 is actually released at which time Spring.NET will officially support the officially released version of NH3 :)

The Spring.NET nightly downloads may be accessed here: http://www.springframework.net/downloads/nightly/